# UserJS. Функция в контексте страницы

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userjs

Здравствуйте.
Создаю пользовательский скрипт для FireFox (плагин GreaseMonkey). Функции, которые я объявил в UserJS не доступны в контексте страницы. Например.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==

function go(){
    alert("Okey");
};
body=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
span=document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML="<INPUT type=button onclick=\"javascript:go();\" value=click />";
body.appendChild(span);
```

При клике на кнопке в консоль падает ошибка

```
go is not defined
```

То есть в контексте страницы такой функции не существует- она есть только в контексте расширения GreaseMonkey.
Как можно решить эту проблему, сохранив при этом кроссбраузерность UserJS? Не хочется писать нечто вроде

```
if (browser=="firefox"){
    span.innerHTML="Вариант для FireFox";
} else {
    span.innerHTML="Вариант для Chrome, Opera, Safari";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых `unsafeWindow` доступен не во всех браузерах, а во вторых он тоже имеет кучу ограничений. Для получения полноценного кроссбраузерного доступа к текущей странице я делал обычно так:

```
var extension = function() {
    // We're free!

    // Теперь, к примеру, мы можем полноценно юзать jQuery, если он был подключен
    $('.some-selector').click(/* ... */);
}

// Выбираемся из песочницы
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = '(' + extension.toString() + ')();';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Неплохо, пожалуй я так и сделаю.

Comment: Вариант отличный, но для 100% совместимости лучше делать так.  

    script.textContent = extension.toString().replace(/^.*?\{|\}.*?$/g, '');

Comment: Никому не интересная, занудная мелочь - вместо 

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]

Можно

    document.head

Comment: Словил странный баг  

    console.log((function(){re1=/ваня/; txt1='ваня'}).toString());
Результат  

    function () {
        re1 = /20=O/;
        txt1 = "\u0432\u0430\u043D\u044F";
    }
То есть регулярки неправильно декодируются, если содержат кириллицу.

Comment: В первом случае, наверное, можно так обойти это:

    rel = new RegExp('ваня');

А второй вариант вполне валидный:

    console.log("\u0432\u0430\u043D\u044F"); // "ваня"

PS А это в каком браузере?

Comment: Потому что в Вашем случае все выполняется в пространстве имён функции `extension` и например имея внутри функцию `myclick`, которую надо повесить на событие `onclick` через` innerHTML`, то при клике на элементе естественно увидим ошибку в консоли, что `myclick is undefined`.  
В моем варианте пространство имён `window`.

Comment: Понятно. Я бы просто в расширении функции явно задавал:

    window.myclick = function() { ... }

Answer (score 1):

GM исполняет юзерcкрипт в собственном глобальном контексте, а контекст страницы доступен как объект [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow). Соответственно,

```
unsafeWindow.foo = function () {
    alert( 'Userscripts are good, mmkay?' );
}
```

Еще существует ключ метаданных [`@unwrap`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40unwrap), который запрещает заворачивать юзерскрипт в анонимную функцию.

Comment: Обязательно прочтите ссылки!

Comment: Вы правы. Я именно так и делал, но у меня много функций, которые должны быть добавлены через innerHTML, в итоге получается необходимость делать много присваиваний unsafeWindow.  
Можно конечно обернуть все эти функции в класс, но потом все обращения придется через имя класса делать.
Это решение конечно, но мне оно не совсем нравится.